# How much communication is necessary between client and server for JWT verification?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm really confused about the specifics of JWT verification. I know it has to be done on the server, but the JWT is also generated/signed on the server.

So that means that (confused about the bold parts):

- User makes request to login (user/password get sent to server)
- Server checks for user existence and proper password, returns signed JWT
- Client receives JWT, **sends it back to the server to verify?**
- **Server verifies JWT, then sends OK response back?**

If the server is the one generating and signing the JWT, why is verification necessary at all? The only way this makes sense to me is if you verify on the frontend, which I know is a big no-no.

I'm obviously unclear about this. Is someone able to fill in the blanks for me?

Comment: There is a network inspector in most browsers if you want to find out what's going on.

Comment: Am I right in assuming those steps though? Seems like I've overthought it, doesn't feel right

Comment: it depends on what flow policy you have, but normally it would have at least 03 steps. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/41334645/3256489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you have two apis on two different servers(or you can image it's on a serverless platform so that there's no directly shared resources) - `[POST]login` and `[GET]orders`. Your `[POST]login` API will generate a JWT token if the given credential is valid and `[GET]orders` will return placed orders only for authorized clients. Then the steps should be

1. Your client will send a `[POST]login` request. The api will verify the credential and generate a JWT token. The client should store the received JWT token.
2. When the client wants to send `[GET]orders` requests, it should put the JWT token in the request or it will get 401 unauthorized.
3. Then server verifies whether the given JWT token is valid or not. Not only JWT token itself can be verified but also there can be several data to verify([rfc7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) has several optional claims so that you can use them or you can put custom data to verify, ex: privileges).

JWT is very useful when you have multiple RESTful API endpoints. You don't need to manage sessions(for sure you can) and as it can store lot of data, you can easily get clients' information without retrieving it from db or something else.

Comment: This is great, thank you. As a follow up, for something "idle" like just keeping the user logged in, would that involve a check on an interval (say every minute or so) that checks if the user is still logged in or not using the same pattern you described?

Comment: When you use JWT, you don't need to check actively. The authenticator(or APIs) will verify the token when requests come.
There're many ways to set and manage expiry of JWT tokens, one of the possible way is to use the 'exp(expiration time)' claim(refer to rfc7519). Set the claim when you generate JWT token and verifies when you receives requests. And then just set exp with enough time(ex: +1 month). In this way, you'll need to implement refresh logic. You can generate permanent tokens (it's dangerous) and for sure everything depends on the characteristics of your service.